# How to add textures on top of an image plane?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shader-nodes

So I've made a meal box in blender from a Die-cut by dropping and using an image plane.

What im having trouble with is adding cardboard textures and other paper-like textures to it on top of the image texture.

What can I do to keep connecting and adding more and more textures without it removing the main design elements?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a *Color > Mix Color* (previously *Mix RGB*) to blend your base texture with a paper texture, here I've used the *Overlay* option and put the *Factor* at 1. According to the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes#Overlay), *Overlay combines Multiply and Screen blend modes.[4] Where the base layer is light, the top layer becomes lighter; where the base layer is dark, the top becomes darker; where the base layer is mid grey, the top is unaffected*:

[image]